# Is there any possibility to Exporting the private key from the PKCS12 format by using Java Keytool?

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, private-key, keytool

I have created `keystore` by using `Java Keytool`. Below are the steps i tried.

**Preparing the certificate:**

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigncert -keystore "C:\path\keystore.jks" -validity 365 -keysize 2048
```

**Convert the JKS keystore to industry standard PKCS12 keystore**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\path\keystore.jks -destkeystore C:\path\keystore.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

**Export the client certificate**

```
keytool -export -alias selfsigncert -keystore C:\path\keystore.p12 -rfc -file C:\path\my_self_cert.crt
```

Next step is to export unencrypted private key, To achieve this I could not find any command on `Java keytool`

I found openssl related commands only to generate **private key** like below

```
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out private_key.pem
```

Note:

- openssl is not installed in my system ie `windows 11`
- Git is not installed in my machine

Can we able to achieve this by using same `Java keytool` rather than go with `openssl`?

Comment: Just curious, does it work with openssl? In that case, why do you need to use keytool specifically?

Comment: Hi @NurioFernández
As i stated in above question, openssl is not installed in my system, Only JDK is installed, so i am using the keytool to generate certificate and finding way to get private key using the same keytool.

Comment: *Only JDK is installed* So write some Java code.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Using java keytool i achieved my usecase.

**Creating new Keystore:**

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias dev.wso2.com -keystore "C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.jks" -validity 4000
```

**Convert to pkcs12 format:**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.jks -destkeystore C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

**Export public certificate:**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias dev.wso2.com -rfc -file "C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.pem" -keystore "C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.jks"
```

**import certificate into trust store**

```
keytool -import -alias dev.wso2.com -file "C:\dummypath\resources\security\devwso2.pem" -keystore "C:\dummypath\resources\security\client-truststore.jks"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm recommend you to use free GUI program. https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html